# Propene with Hydrogen. Name the catalyst used

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

Which industrial process uses a similar reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about formation of propane(alkene to alkane) , then the catalyst commonly used is Nickel along with heat. Also, Platinum or Palladium can be used instead of the above combination.
The process or reaction is **Hydrogenation**

Comment: More precisely **Catalytic hydrogenation**